# Find the neighbours in a 2D array with repeat strategy

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, nearest-neighbor

Exist a simple and compact way (non recursive) to find all neighbours at a distance D from a given  coordinate inside a 2D array with height H and width W using a repeat strategy.

[image]

For example in the image above we have a 2D array/matrix with height and width 3. Now what Im trying to archive is to get the neighbours of element 2 with distance/hop 1 which in this case are 7,8,6,1,2,0,4,5,3 (circled in red) using a repeat strategy(p.s without creating a bigger matrix with 9 small matrixes).

Does anyone know a way/algorithm of how to get this thx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of the question ,this can be achieved by nested loops.

Assuming that you have 'x' and 'y' coordinates for the target value, hop as 'h'.

Assuming array size to be **m X n**

Then make two loops:

```
  Outer loop 'i' from x-h to x+h

    Inner loop 'j' from y-h to y+h

        Elements arr[i%m][j%n] are your neighbors
```

UPDATE: I have updated the code as per my understanding of the problem. This way, u can go upto 'hop' steps, and also u will **not** get 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException'.

Comment: No, it's not so simple. For example in the first image the neighbours of element "2" are 7,8,6,1,2,0,4,5,3 with hop 1 so if I use your algorithm I will get only 1,2,4,5. I have to use a repeat strategy when the index go out of bounds, I want it to re-enter  from the other side like in the last iamge

Comment: So hop 1 means u can go upto 2 places from the point, right?
This way the output of second image will have all the numbers within blue boundary, right?

Comment: as for your UPDATE I want that when I get ArrayIndexOutOfBound I reenter from the opposite side of the matrix, for example in the first image coordinates (0,3) will produce ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException because 3 is outside. What I want in this case is to reenter in the matrix from the opposite side, so coordinate (0,3) will corespond to coordinate (0,0) or coord (0,4)->(0,1) or (4,4)->(1,1)

Comment: Oh! Ok ok..! 
Now have a look at the code. It should work